# How to make exact unicode characters take priority over ASCII versions?

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode, full-text-search, diacritics

I have a database with the names of German towns and cities such as Munich and Münster.

If I query like so:

```sql
SELECT name,
       MATCH(name) AGAINST('+mün*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM place_names
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

I get the same relevance value for all places that contain `mun`, `mün` or any other text that flattens to `mun` when not accounting for diacritics. In other words, searching for `mun` or `mün` gives the exact same results.

How can I configure my database such that searching for `mün` will give higher relevance for words that actually contain the letter `ü`, but still also consider `u` a match?

Comment: Noway. Either the same relevance or one of them not matched. This depends on the collation. You may use collation which treates both as matched ones and use additional matching using sensitive collation which will put strict matching up.

Comment: Then how do I set up two different collations for the same database(/table?) and use both in the same query? For example by taking the `GREATEST()` of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE place_names (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));
> CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx ON place_names (name);
> INSERT INTO place_names (name) VALUES ('Munich'), ('Münster');
> SELECT * FROM place_names;
> ```
>
> | id | name |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Munich |
> | 2 | Münster |

> ```
> SELECT name,
>        MATCH(name) AGAINST('+mün*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
> FROM place_names
> ORDER BY relevance DESC;
> ```
>
> | name | relevance |
> | --- | --- |
> | Munich | 0.000000001885928302414186 |
> | Münster | 0.000000001885928302414186 |

> ```
> ALTER TABLE place_names ADD COLUMN name2 VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_bin AS (name) STORED;
> CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx2 ON place_names (name2);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT name,
>        MATCH(name) AGAINST('+mün*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance,
>        MATCH(name2) AGAINST('+mün*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance2
> FROM place_names
> ORDER BY relevance DESC;
> ```
>
> | name | relevance | relevance2 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Munich | 0.000000001885928302414186 | 0 |
> | Münster | 0.000000001885928302414186 | 0.0906190574169159 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=413da886821e7ca26dc004988d92ede1)*

Hence

```sql
SELECT name,
       MATCH(name) AGAINST('+mün*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM place_names
ORDER BY MATCH(name2) AGAINST('+mün*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you. But making a separate column to hold the same data with a different collation would require me to duplicate a lot of data. Is there really no way to "interpret" a column with two different collations at query time?

Comment: @theberzi FTI uses definite collation, MATCH .. AGAINST cannot use collation other than column's one. By the shown way your task needs two separate collations - so you need 2 separate FTI. FTI uses column's collation - so you need 2 separate columns. FTI cannot be created by virtual generated column - so you need twice disk space. Maybe there exists some another solution, but I cannot find it now. Except the sorting by non-FTS expression (LIKE or REGEX).

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be:

```
WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST ('+mün*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
ORDER BY name LIKE '%Mün%' COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DESC, relevance DESC
```

Another thing to note is the existence of collations `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci` in MySQL 8.0 -- "Accent Sensitive and Case Insensitive".  (However, that would not match "Mun" at all.)